# Non-Latin characters in username for FTP

Tags: unicode, ftp, interop, rfc

I tried to find the list of characters allowed in username for FTP but the RFC is not very specific. What ftp servers and clients support user names in Unicode? Special characters? Is there a generally accepted spec that explains the list of characters allowed in FTP usernames? (googling was of no help to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) 5.3.2:

```
<username> ::= <string>
<string> ::= <char> | <char><string>
<char> ::= any of the 128 ASCII characters except <CR> and <LF>
```

Later RFCs (like proposed standard [RFC 3659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659)) talk about UTF-8 extensions, but only in the context of pathnames and file contents encoding.

So you can only depend on ASCII, but I suspect in practice most clients and servers support  UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, I found "telnet string" words but somehow missed the definition of it. I expected to see something that disallows special characters like \ or % but looks like such characters are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode using `UTF-8` because most FTP servers will work with UTF-8.