# How can I parse a FTP URL with the username or password having special characters?

Tags: ruby, ftp, uri, url-encoding

I am trying to parse a FTP URL that has some special characters like `@` in the username and password:

```
username:p@sswrd@ftp.myhost.com/mypath
```

When I try:

```
URI.parse(url)
```

I get:

> URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme ftp does not accept registry part: username:p@sswrd@ftp.myhost.com (or bad hostname?)

Then, I tried to encode the url:

```
url = URI.encode(url, '@')
```

But also got another error:

> URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme ftp does not accept registry part: username:p%40sswrd%40ftp.myhost.com (or bad hostname?)

Finally, I tried another solution:

```
URI::FTP.build(:userinfo => 'username:p@sswrd', :host=>'ftp.myhost.com', :path => '/mypath')
```

But I also got an error:

> URI::InvalidComponentError: bad component(expected user component): p@ssword

I am using ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp=Net::FTP.new
ftp.connect("ftp.myhost.com",21)
ftp.login("username","p@sswd")
ftp.getbinaryfile("/mypath"){|data| puts data}
ftp.close
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ftp server supports unicode:

```
URI::FTP.build(:userinfo => 'username:p%00%40sswrd', :host=>'ftp.myhost.com', :path => '/mypath')
```

should work. As indicated by [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466831/non-latin-characters-in-username-for-ftp).

But just realized you tried encoding and it failed.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set passive mode as I was receiving the following error:

```
425 Could not open data connection to port XXXXX: Connection timed out
```

I did this like so:

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp = Net::FTP.new
ftp.passive = true
ftp.connect("ftp.myhost.com",21)
ftp.login("username","p@sswd")
ftp.getbinaryfile("/mypath"){|data| puts data}
ftp.close
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to parse an ftp url and open it like this:

```
ftp_regex = /\/\/(.*)?\:(.*)?@([^\/]*)?\/(.*)/
user, password, host, path = ftp_file_url.match(ftp_regex).captures

ftp = Net::FTP.new
ftp.connect(host, 21)
ftp.login(user, password)
ftp.passive = true
file = ftp.getbinaryfile(path, nil)
```